# Criar e manipular array associativo multidimensional

Tags: java

Como posso criar em Java um array associativo multidimensional?
Algo semelhante a isto:

```
Array = {
    "carro 1" : Array {
        "portas" : 5,
        "cor" : "preto",
        "km" : 10670
    },
    "carro 2" : Array {
        "portas" : 3,
        "cor" : "vermelho",
        "km" : 70334
    },
}
```

E como posso depois iterar com um for e ler cada elemento?
Eu cheguei a encontrar esta class [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) mas não compreendi como a posso utilizar para o fim que procuro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a ideia é ter uma lista de Carros é mais fácil criares um objeto Carro ou Veiculo com os atributos que precisares, por exemplo:

```
class Carro
{
   private String nome;
   private int portas;
   private String cor;
   private int km;

   Carro (String nome, int portas, String cor, int km)
   {
      this.nome   = nome;
      this.portas = portas;
      this.cor    = cor;
      this.km     = km;
   }
   public String getNome () { return nome;   }
   public int getPortas  () { return portas; }
   public String getCor  () { return cor;    }
   public int getKm      () { return km;     }

   public void setNome   ( int nome   ) { this.nome   = nome;   }
   public void setPortas ( int portas ) { this.portas = portas; }
   public void setCor    ( String cor ) { this.cor    = cor;    }
   public void setKm     ( int km     ) { this.km     = km;     }

   //Restantes métodos como clone, equals, compareTo, toString, etc..
}
```

Podes usar um `ArrayList<value>` para colocar os carros numa lista.

```
Carro carro = new Carro ("carro 1", 3, "preto", 120000);

ArrayList<Carro> listaDeCarros = new ArrayList<Carro>();
listaDeCarros.add(carro);

// Para percorrer o ArrayList:

for (Carro carro_temp : listaDeCarros) 
{
    Log.e("carros", "" + carro_temp.getNome());
}
```

Ou podes usar o `Map<key,value>` que tem a cada chave associado um valor. A *key*(chave) pode ser um código ou um nome (do carro) e o *value* (valor) pode ser o próprio objeto.

```
Carro carro2 = new Carro ("carro 2", 5, "verde", 143122);

Map<String, Carro> mapDeCarros = new Map<String, Carro>();
mapDeCarros.put(carro.getNome(), carro);

// Para percorrer o Map:

for (Map.Entry<String, Carro> entry : mapDeCarros.entrySet())
{
    Log.e("carros", "" + entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue().toString());
    //                   nome/carro
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZlKKZb)

Comment: eu estou agora a tentar colocar todas as instancias do meu object num `ArrayList` tal como indicou mas dá erro. Diz `cannot resolve symbol 'add'` e dentro do add diz que a class carro não é reconhecida, estou a usar o seu código sem grandes alterações

Comment: Como podes ver aqui http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29 existe o método add.

Comment: Que IDE estás a usar? É que tens de fazer `import` de algumas bibliotecas (o IDE costuma fazer sozinho)

Comment: estou a usar o Android Studio com auto import, eu sei que esse método existe mas por alguma razão não está a ser reconhecido no meu código

Comment: Que estranho. Deveria funcionar, testei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: de qualquer forma arranjei um workarround usando um `public static List<TableHelper> tableList = Arrays.asList(...);`, obrigado @Jorge

Comment: Tá com um erro no Ideone, tá faltando o `e` no `Log.("carro"...)`

Comment: Vê este: http://ideone.com/ZlKKZb