# Existe uma estrutura dados tipo array associativo em Java?

Tags: java, array, string

Bem, eu estou querendo denominar uma Array de Strings em Java, mas eu queria que fosse, por exemplo:

```
String[] symbols;
```

E que pudesse ser declarada assim:

```
symbols["name"] = "Tiago";
```

Eu sei que não existe Array assim, mas de alguma outra maneira, tem como?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46570/criar-e-manipular-array-associativo-multidimensional

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `HashMap` para fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```java
Map<String, Integer> vehicles = new HashMap<>();
vehicles.put("BMW", 5);
vehicles.put("Mercedes", 3);
vehicles.put("Audi", 4);
vehicles.put("Ford", 10);
```

Veja mais sobre a interface `Map`, e a classe `HashMap` em:

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

[Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu cara, exatamente o que eu precisava :D

Comment: Vinícius, eu editei a tua resposta para usar generics e linkar o javadocs do java 8. Fica a dica para a próxima vez.